# Sci-fi comic/graphic novel about augmented reality and intrusive advertising / microtransactions and telepathy

Tags: story-identification, comics

Setting: Near future

Released: Within the last 10 years I think.  Was only one book/issue to my knowledge.

Read: About 2012.

A company comes out with glasses that allow their users to overlay/augment the appearance of the world and share those view with other users.  The views were created by the creators' imaginations.

The creating company starts forcefully injecting advertisements into the created worlds.  Rather than having royalties, etc the company starts having the device listen to what's happening around the users and charging them pennies every time a song is heard (even if it's just someone humming it and not the artist performing it).  There are opt-out features for a lot of these issues, but if any show tries to tell users how it gets slowed down or cancelled.

Eventually some people try to stop using the devices, and find that they're now telepathically linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comic is *[Vision Machine](http://comicsalliance.com/greg-pak-vision-machine-free/)*.  I was wrong about the number of issues.  It was a 3 issue short.  However, I read a copy that was all three issues combined in a single volume, hence my confusion.

[image: An explanation of the iEye]

Comment: Good work! What made you remember the answer?

Comment: I didn't, but my former roommate and I went through his collection and were able to find it.